# Highcharts - Getting chart on click event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create 9 pie charts with the same options in a single page, I'm using the following function to create them:

```
function newChart(series_id, div_name) {
    this.chart = {
        height: 450,
        marginBottom: 70
    },
    this.title = {
        floating: true
    },
    this.subtitle = {
        floating: true
    },
    this.legend = pie_legend,
            this.tooltip = tooltip_,
            this.plotOptions = {
                pie: {
                    showInLegend: true,
                    size: '100%',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOut: function () {
                                setTranslation(this, false);
                            },
                            mouseOver: function () {
                                setTranslation(this, true);
                            },
                            click: function () {
                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                if (isNumber(drilldown))
                                {
                                    chart3.series[0] = chart3.drilldown.series[drilldown];
                                    require(['jquery', 'charts'], function ($, charts) {
                                        $(function () {
                                            var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                                            charts.pie(div_name, chart3);
                                            $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
                                        });
                                    });
                                    chart3.colors = chart_colors;
                                }
                                else {
                                    chart3.series[0] = series_id.series[0];
                                    require(['jquery', 'charts'], function ($, charts) {
                                        $(function () {
                                            var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                                            charts.pie(div_name, chart3);
                                            $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
                                        });
                                    });
                                    chart3.colors = ["#FF7070", "#FFC870", "#B0DDC2", "#82CA9D", "#409661"];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            fontSize: '16px'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
    this.colors = ["#FF7070", "#FFC870", "#B0DDC2", "#82CA9D", "#409661"],
            this.series = [],
            this.drilldown = {
                series: []
            }
}
;
```

On the click event I want to use the same object I'm creating to create the functions. However I can't find a way to make it dynamic, if I manually change chart3 for chartX, they're individually created correctly and work correctly. My question is how do I get the chart object inside the click function, I can't use 'this' because in that scope it's retrieving a point in the chart (a slice of a pie chart in this case). So I want to get something like:

```
    click: function () {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    if (isNumber(drilldown))
    {
        thisChart.series[0] = thisChart.drilldown.series[drilldown];
        require(['jquery', 'charts'], function ($, charts) {
            $(function () {
                var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                charts.pie(div_name, thisChart);
                $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
            });
        });
        thisChart.colors = chart_colors;
    }
    else {
        thisChart.series[0] = series_id.series[0];
        require(['jquery', 'charts'], function ($, charts) {
            $(function () {
                var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                charts.pie(div_name, thisChart);
                $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
            });
        });
        thisChart.colors = ["#FF7070", "#FFC870", "#B0DDC2", "#82CA9D", "#409661"];
    }
}
```

I've read that binding the function could help but I have no idea how I would do that, also I tried passing the same object as parameter of the function but it doesn't work, and tried using it as a string variable to pass as an object in the function but it's not being considered an object or it gives me errors.

I'm completely new to Javascript (like 3-4 weeks experience), so bear with me. I could just create an independent chart object for each graph, repeating the code 9 times and just changing the chart3 part to chart1, chart2, etc and it works, but I want to make it simpler.

Comment: Small suggestion: try using functions to separate your code a little bit more. There isn't any hard and fast rule that says "don't indent your code 10 times" but it does make things harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow asking questions helps me come up wit the answer, reading about bracket notation I came up with the following:

```
click: function () {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    var chartName = name;
    if (isNumber(drilldown))
    {
        window[chartName].series[0] = window[chartName].drilldown.series[drilldown];
        require(['jquery', 'charts'], function ($, charts) {
            $(function () {
                var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                charts.pie(div_name, window[chartName]);
                $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
            });
        });
        window[chartName].colors = chart_colors;
    }
    else {
        window[chartName].series[0] = series_id.series[0];
        require(['jquery', 'charts'], function ($, charts) {
            $(function () {
                var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                charts.pie(div_name, window[chartName]);
                $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
            });
        });
        window[chartName].colors = ["#FF7070", "#FFC870", "#B0DDC2", "#82CA9D", "#409661"];
    }
}
```

I pass the name when I create the new chart:

```
chart1 = new newChart(series1,"chart-pie1","chart1");
chart2 = new newChart(series2,"chart-pie2","chart2")
chart3 = new newChart(series3,"chart-pie3","chart3");
```

And it works how I want it to work now. Anyway I'd appreciate suggestions on code minimizing. I know my code is extremely repetitive, I'm just learning javascript so my coding is not really efficient or simple enough.